# Failed creating repository

Tags: apt, ppa

I try to create my first PPA package. It seems to work to add the repository.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unixinfo/openshell
[sudo] password for developer: 
 The OpenShell (opsh) command-line interface
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~unixinfo/+archive/ubuntu/openshell
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpytohca83/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpytohca83/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 8B747352 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpytohca83/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 8B747352: public key "Launchpad PPA for Niklas Larsson" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

But then after `apt-get update` I get status 404 from the repo and I can't install the package. What can I do about this?

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unixinfo/openshell/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unixinfo/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the builds have succeeded, they are still pending publication as you can see under the "Status" heading at https://launchpad.net/~unixinfo/+archive/ubuntu/openshell/+packages and in the screenshot below:

[image]

I am not sure how long it takes for them to be published, but it is definitely not instantaneous.